# Using Docker-Compose with storage options (size)

Tags: docker, size, limit, docker-compose, quota

I can apply disk size quota with **"--storage-opt size=1536M"** argument when working under devicemapper. For example:

```
docker run -dt --name testing --storage-opt size=1536M ubuntu
```

**the problem is**, how can I do this by using **docker-compose**, via a compose *.yml file.

thanks.

#### AN ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION:

Use devicemapper as default storage driver for Docker and set basesize for every container.

To use devicemapper as the default:

1) `apt-get install lvm2 thin-provisioning-tools`

2) change /etc/default/docker as this:

`--storage-driver devicemapper --storage-opt dm.basesize=3G`

3) do these one by one:

```
systemctl stop docker
systemctl daemon-reload
rm -rf /var/lib/docker
systemctl start docker
```

4) now your containers have only 3GB space. In addition, you can define vol. space when using RUN command with devicemapper (size must be equal or bigger than basesize). For eg:

```
docker run --storage-opt size=1536M ubuntu
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
storage_opt:
  size: '1G'
```

as in https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/

Comment: Have you tested this ? Whats your docker version? I get 'Unsupported config option' on 18.05.0-ce

Comment: If anyone else finds this, the 'storage_opt' is currently not available in V3 compose files (3.7 being current as of writing). It was however available in V2 but was removed to V3 (which is apparently a complete re-implementation). So don't waste your time with storage_opts for compose files with V3!

Comment: to be more specific it is in version '2.1'. It concerns because a specific version of rancher uses docker compose 2.0 and 1.0

Comment: I tested with docker-compose v2, not sure what is my docker version then